# Como fazer esse tipo de relacionamento no Django?

Tags: python, django, relacionamento, chave-estrangeira, entidade-relacionamento

Eu tenho o models "Assinante":

```
class Assinante(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nome", max_length=32, null=False, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField("Telefone", max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField("E-mail", null=True, blank=True)
    plans = models.ForeignKey("Plano", null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField("Data da assinatura", null=False, blank=False)
    due_date = models.DateField("Vencimento", null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Assinantes"
```

E o models "Plano":

```
class Plano(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nome", max_length=32, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField("Valor pago", default=00.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Planos"
```

Como é possível notar em "Assinante" eu tenho uma chave estrangeira referenciando o "Plano" do "Assinante". O que eu quero é ter um campo em "Assinante" que armazene o valor da variável **price** setada em "Plano", mas esse valor precisa ser relacionado a tabela do plano escolhido na variável **plans**, por exemplo eu cadastrei um plano de nome **Gold** com o preço 79,99, quando eu adicionar um assinante e setar o plano dele como **Gold** quero que automaticamente o valor da coluna **Valor pago** seja 79,99. Exemplo abaixo.

Eu preciso que isso funcione em uma tabela do Django-Admin, alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
Assinantes
| Nome   | Telefone     | E-mail            | Planos    | Valor pago |
| Carlos | 88 952684179 | exemplo@uhuuu.com | Gold      | 79,99      |
| Mario  | 88 910101799 | exemplo@uhuuu.com | Platinium | 119,99     |
```

```
Planos
| Plano     | Preço  |
| Prata     | 29,99  |
| Gold      | 79,99  |
| Platinium | 119,99 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi só precisas de mostrar na tabela do admin do django os dados dessa forma. Para tal, crias uma classe no ficheiro admin, com o seguinte:

```
class AssinanteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = Assinante
    list_display = ('name', 'phone', 'email', 'get_name', 'get_price')
    search_fields = ['name', 'phone']

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.plans.name

    def get_price(self, obj):
        return obj.plans.price

admin.site.register(Assinante, AssinanteAdmin)
```

Ou seja, criar as definições das tabelas e para a tua FK crias uma função para cada atributo que queres mostrar na grid.

Resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, obrigado me ajudou muito!

Comment: Nesse exemplo, se eu alterar o valor do plano todos os relacionamentos são atualizados correto? mas se eu quiser que para novos cadastros ele utilize o novo valor mas cadastros ativos ele respeite o valor original tem como? algo como inserir o valor da tabela e planos na tabela de assinantes?