# Multiplos models - tres apps

Tags: python, django

Boa noite prezados... meu projeto de TCC, tem três apps: turmas, salas e alocar. eu preciso fazer as alocações das turmas nas salas, depois de alocadas preciso marcar um boleano da turma como alocada, e um boleano da sala como indisponivel. abaixo envio o codigo para ficar melhor elucidado. como devo implementar isso? estou empacado nesse ponto, confesso que sou inexperiente com django.

## app salas

```
class Sala(models.Model):
    bloco = models.ForeignKey(Bloco, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sala = models.CharField('Sala: ', unique=True, max_length=50)
    capmaxima = models.IntegerField('Cap. Máxima: ')
    disponivel = models.BooleanField('Disponivel', default=True)
    ocupada = models.BooleanField('Ocupada', default=False)
    internet = models.BooleanField('Internet', default=False)
    projetor = models.BooleanField('Projetor', default=True)
    computador = models.BooleanField('Computador', default=False)
```

## app turmas

```
class Turma(models.Model):
    turma = models.CharField('Turma', max_length=20)
    curso = models.CharField('Curso', null=False, max_length=50)
    periodo = models.CharField('Periodo', null=False, max_length=50)
    disciplina = models.CharField('Disciplina', max_length=50)
    qtdalunos = models.IntegerField('Qtd')
    professor = models.CharField('Professor', max_length=50)
    alocada = models.BooleanField('Alocada', default=False)
    internet = models.BooleanField('Internet', default=False)
    projetor = models.BooleanField('Projetor', default=False)
    computador = models.BooleanField('Computador', default=False)
```

## alocar

```
class Alocar(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField('Data', auto_now=True, blank=True)
    dias = [
        ('A Confirmar', 'A Confirmar'),
        ('Segunda', 'Segunda'),
        ('Terça', 'Terça'),
        ('Quarta', 'Quarta'),
        ('Quinta', 'Quinta'),
        ('Sexta', 'Sexta'),
        ('Sábado', 'Sábado'),
    ]
    dia = models.CharField('Dia', max_length=11, choices=dias, 
    default='A Confirmar')
    horario = models.ForeignKey(Horario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.SET())
    sala = models.ForeignKey(Sala, on_delete=models.SET())
```

Obrigado pela atenção de voces.

Comment: Parece que estás a misturar aqui um pouco os conceitos. Django tem o conceito de App, mas não é o modelo ou objeto (tabela de base de dados), mas algo mais abrangente, "App em Django e um dos grandes responsáveis por sua flexibilidade e alto reaproveitamento de componentes.". Em relação às tuas dúvidas. Explica um pouco melhor o que pretendes fazer, vais criar uma Web App com recurso do Amin do Django? Que código já fizeste para chegar a esse objetivo? As classes do teu models.py não chegam.

Comment: Boa noite...o que esta impedindo o meu avanço é que preciso alocar uma turma numa sala, depois de alocada tem que mostrar que a sala esta indisponivel e a turma esta alocada, os fields sao boleanos...creio que isso deve ser feito no methodo save_model no admin.py, todavia nao sei como iniciar ...os codigos dos models sao os que estao logo acima, o model alocar tem duas chaves estrangeiras, turma e sala....quando eu digo apps sao no mesmo projeto, mesmo diretorio

Comment: Viva, partilho uma reposta a umas dúvidas que tirei à dias (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437747/como-fazer-esse-tipo-de-relacionamento-no-django/438675#438675), já deves ter o ficheiro admin.py, adiciona com base neste exemplo para teres acesso no admin, não te esqueças que o admin vem inativo por defeito, tens de descomentar uma linha no settings.py e 2/3 no urls.py. Quando tiveres o admin ativo, na prática não precisas de definir nenhum save, a framework já disponibiliza o CRUD por ti, só irás em caso especiais, mas a seu tempo.

Comment: Amigo boa noite...percebi que voce tem conhecimento do assunto...fiz outro post, com o seguinte titulo "Deletar sem dar erro"...estou correndo contra o tempo para entregar meu TCC... se possível ajude-me muitissimo obrigado..

Comment: Viva, já trabalho com Django à muito tempo. Efetivamente, quando os posts são sobre trabalhos académicos, nem sei se devo ajudar, fico sempre reticente, principalmente quando não tem esforço de investigação visivel, e por outro lado, porque estou a ajudar quem está a aprender posso estar a retirar parte desta aprendizagem individual, que é a pesquisa, ler documentação etc. Percebes? Outra questão, se nesta questão tens a solução, partilha numa resposta (depois do teu TCC terminar), e assim podes ajudar o próximo, será um pouco o espirito desta plataforma.

Answer (score 0):

É só você setar disponível para `False` quando realizar uma alocação

Isso foi faz na view, dentro no método que vc criar quando definir as datas, que turma é você vai lá e muda o valor booleano:

```
def alocar_view(request):
  ...
  ...
  turma.alocada = True
  sala.disponivel = False
```

Comment: #esse é meu form

        class Meta:
            model = Alocar
            fields = ['turma','sala','dia','horario']



#essa é minha view

    form = AddAlocFom(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():

        form.sala.disponivel = False
        form.turma.alocada = True

        form.save()
        form = AddAlocFom()

#deu esse erro
AttributeError at /addaloc
'AddAlocFom' object has no attribute 'sala'